# How to get all possible combinations of pairs with unique elements

Tags: python, iteration

I have a list of even N elements and would like to get a list of lists of all possible and unique pairs, e.g.:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
result: [[(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)], [(1,2), (3,5), (4,6)] ...
```

So each list I get as the result should have N/2 elements (pairs with unique numbers). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771687/how-to-get-all-possible-unique-variants-from-all-possible-combinations) seemed similar to my problem, although the answer gives the lists with 2 combinations only and it doesn't work for N > 4; not sure if it's possible to rework this solution for my purposes.

I suppose that one possible option is to:

1. iterate through each possible order of N numbers (123456, 123465 ... 654321)
2. create a list of pairs for each following 2 elements ([1,2,3,4,5,6] -> [(12), (34), (56)])
3. sort those pairs and eliminate duplicates

But it feels that there should be a more elegant solution, would be grateful for help :)

Comment: FYI don't use the variable name `list` as it is already pre-defined by Python and could cause errors down the road.

Comment: Look at the `itertools` module...

Comment: I think you might really be looking for unique *partitions* of your list into pairs.  That's a fairly hard problem in a general sense (partitions of list length `n` into subsets size `m`), but if you're always looking at short lists like your sample (low n and m), you can do it very fast.  Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken,

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

x = list(itertools.combinations(itertools.combinations(l, 2), 3))
```

does what you want.

Comment: Thanks, although I believe that's not the case. The result of this code starts with:
"((1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4))"
And what I need is sets of (in this case - set of 3) pairs in which every element is unique (so in every set, all N numbers are used).

Comment: @KrzysztofSieja, try `[[p[i: i + 2] for i in range(0, len(p), 2)] for p in permutations(l)]`